# geolocating self join too slow

Tags: sql, geolocation, sas, self-join

I am trying to get the count of all records within 50 miles of each record in a huge table (1m + records), using self join as shown below:

```
proc sql;
    create table lab as
    select distinct a.id, sum(case when b.value="New York" then 1 else 0 end) 
    from latlon a, latlon b
    where a.id <> b.id 
    and geodist(a.lat,a.lon,b.lat,b.lon,"M") <= 50 
    and a.state = b.state;
```

This ran for 6 hours and was still running when i last checked. 
Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

**UPDATE**: My intention is to get the number of new yorkers in a 50 mile radius from every record identified in table latlon which has name, location and latitude/longitude where lat/lon could be anywhere in the world but location will be a person's hometown. I have to do this for close to a dozen towns. Looks like this is the best it could get. I may have to write a C code for this one i guess.

Comment: I don't see why you need to perform a join at all to select the records representing locations within range of **one** chosen location.  If, on the other hand, you want, for **every** record, all the others representing points within 50 miles, then I don't see why you're surprised that it takes forever.

Comment: I do want it for every record. I was wondering if there is a way to do it better and save a few hours since i may have to run this code multiple times for different data sets which are equally huge.

Comment: That query would process every record of the table, and you have a function in one of the conditions, so the database has to process the combinations one by one instead of using sets. Since you are comparing each record with all the records in the same state, supposing that the locations are evenly distributed the query is processing (20,000x20,000)x50=20,000,000,000+ combinations. Also, the `geodist()` function doesn't like like a trivial operation so 6 hours don't sound that bad. You should precompute that distances and store them somewhere.

Comment: The clause `and a.state = b.state` is going to remove a lot of results that are within 50 miles of each other, but are in different states.  Not sure if that is intended, or an optimization bug.

Comment: Please edit your question to give a clear spec. Even your "update" is not clear. (Don't "update" or comment, revise.) [mcve] You want the count of new yorkers < 50 kms from up to circa 12 home towns each?? For god's sake 1. don't calculate a to b *and* b to a 2. put the ny test in a where 3. use count 4. use geospatial dbms capabilities 5. maybe 1st select relevant locations & distances from ny 6. use approximate bounds before geodist. eg distance from ny, eg delta x squared + delta y squared + delta z squared <= pi * (50 squared) 6. read some intros to geospatial query optimization

Answer (score 2):

The `geodist()` function you're using has no chance of exploiting any index. So, you have an algorithn that's O(n**2) at best. That's gonna be slow.

You can take advantage of a simple fact of spherical geometry, though, to get access to an indexable query.  A degree of latitude (north - south) is equivalent to sixty nautical miles, 69 statute miles, or 111.111 km. The British definition of nautical mile was originally equal to a minute. The original Napoleonic meter was defined as one part in ten thousand of the distance from the equator to the pole, also defined as 90 degrees.

(These defintions depend on the assumption that the earth is spherical. It isn't, quite. If you're a civil engineer these definitions break down. If you use them to design a parking lot, it will have some nasty puddles in it when it rains, and will encrooach on the neighbors' property.)

So, what you want is to use a bounding range.  Assuming your latitude values a.lat and b.lat are in degrees, two of them are certainly more than fifty statute miles apart unless

```
     a.lat BETWEEN b.lat - 50.0/69.0 AND b.lat + 50.0/69.0
```

Let's refactor your query. (I don't understand the case stuff about New York so I'm ignoring it. You can add it back.)  This will give the IDs of all pairs of places lying within 50 miles of each other. (I'm using the 21st century JOIN syntax here).

```
select distinct a.id, b.id 
from latlon a
JOIN latlon b    ON a.id<>b.id
                AND a.lat BETWEEN b.lat - 50.0/69.0 AND b.lat + 50.0/69.0
                AND a.state = b.state
                AND geodist(a.lat,a.lon,b.lat,b.lon,"M") <= 50
```

Try creating an index on the table on the `lat` column.  That should help performance a LOT.

Then try creating a compound index on (state, lat, id, lon, value).  Try those columns in the compound index in different orders, if you don't get satisfactory performance acceleration. It's called a *covering index*, because the some of its columns (the first two in this case) are used for quick lookups and the rest are used to provide values that would otherwise have to be fetched from the main table.

Comment: This optimization doesn't work within 50 miles of either pole, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is phrased ambiguously - I'm interpreting it as "give me all (A, B) city pairs within 50 miles of each other." The NYC special case seems to be for a one-off test - the problem is *not* to (trivially, in O(n) time) find all cities within 50 miles of NYC.

Rather than computing Great Circle distances, find Manhattan distances instead, using simple addition, and simple bounding boxes. Given (A, B) city tuples with [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) less than 50 miles, it is straightforward to prune out the few (on diagonals) that have Great Circle (or Euclidean) distance less than 50 miles.

You didn't show us `EXPLAIN` output describing the backend optimizer's plan.

You didn't tell us about indexes on the `latlon` table.

I'm not familiar with the SAS RDBMS. Oracle, MySQL, and others have [geospatial extensions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/spatial-index/) to support multi-dimensional indexing. Essentially, they merge high-order coordinate bits, down to low-order coordinate bits, to construct a quadtree index. The technique could prove beneficial to your query.

Your `DISTINCT` keyword will make a big difference for the query plan. Often it will force a tablescan and a filesort. Consider deleting it.

The equijoin on `state` seems wrong, but maybe you don't care about the tri-state metropolitan area and similar densely populated regions near state borders.

You definitely want the `WHERE` clause to prune out `b` rows that are more than 50 miles from the current `a` row:

1. too far north, OR
2. too far south, OR
3. too far west, OR
4. too far east

Each of those conditionals boils down to a simple range query that the RDBMS backend can evaluate and optimize against an index. Unfortunately, if it chooses the latitude index, any longitude index that's on disk will be ignored, and vice versa. Which motivates using your vendor's geospatial support.

Comment: SAS RDBMS. Ha ha.